# Why won't my MarcTron Admob banner ad show?

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, admob

I'm using Xamarin Forms in Visual Studio 2019.  I have a simple grid layout with a banner ad in the bottom cell of the single column grid.  This is my MainPage.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MarcTron.Plugin.Controls;assembly=Plugin.MtAdmob"
             x:Class="ShaarShamayim.MainPage">

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
.
.
.
            <controls:MTAdView x:Name="myAds" Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="LightGray"></controls:MTAdView>
        </Grid>
    </ContentPage.Content>

</ContentPage>
```

My OnCreate in the Android MainActivity.cs looks like this:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
    Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
    MobileAds.Initialize(ApplicationContext);
    LoadApplication(new App());
}
```

The AndroidManifest contains this:

```
<application android:label="ShaarShamayim.Android">
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID" android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~yyyyyyyyyy" />
</application>
```

And these are the NuGet packages I have installed:

MarcTron.AdMob 1.9.0.3
Xam.Plugin.Geolocator 4.5.0.6
Xamarin Essentials 1.6.1
Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2478
Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads 120.3.0.3

According to everything I've seen online, this should result in a banner ad at the bottom of the screen.  But there's nothing there.  I set the background color of the ad to LightGray so that I could see if it's maybe being pushed off the page, and I get a big gray rectangle at the bottom of the screen.

So what am I doing wrong?  Am I missing something obvious?  The rest of the app works fine; it's just the ad.  And there are no warnings or errors showing.

Thanks,
Lisa

Comment: Maybe like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74868162/how-to-display-a-banner-google-admob-ads-on-xamarin-forms-project

Comment: I wish.  I tried all of their suggestions.  I was excited when I saw that there was an AdsId attribute for the MTAdView control, which I hadn't seen in the documentation.  So I added that, with one of the sample IDs Google offers.  Still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

1. On MainActivity replace MobileAds.Initialize(ApplicationContext) with
   CrossMTAdmob.Current.Init(this, "your_app_id");
2. For the banner try myAds.LoadAd() from a button click at first, to see if it works